# Map tiles to display google maps offline in cordova

Tags: google-maps

Leaflets provides possibility to display maps offline by generating the maptiles using MOBAC (openStreetMap). Can google maps work the same? If can how? Please tell me the tool to generate tiles in google maps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it might be technically possible, Google's TOS don't allow to do that.

Comment: Does it require google maps license for that? If so how to get license and how to implement. Please help me to show the path to do that.

Comment: @limmouyleng: Google simply doesn't allow you to do that and AFAIK there is no possibility to buy a license for this. Why don't you simply use OpenStreetMap. It's free and there is no annoying license.

Comment: Truly I have tried using OpenStreetMap, but it provides a load of map tiles with much capacity. Is there way to reduce the size? I have posted question in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857207/offline-maps-in-cordova-using-leaflets-make-my-app-stores-much-capacity